# GraphQL parameters for an exists filter in API Platform

Tags: graphql, api-platform.com

I have setup an exists filter for an entity:

```
#[ApiFilter(ExistsFilter::class, properties: ['firstName', 'lastName'])]
```

I can then run the query just fine:

```
query accounts {
  accounts(exists: {firstName: true}) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I would like to parameterize the exists filter. The closest I have got is this:

**Query**

```
query getAccounts($exists: [AccountFilter_exists]) {
  accounts(exists: $exists) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Parameters**

```
{
  "exists": {"firstName": true}
}
```

But I get this error message:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Variable \"$exists\" got invalid value {\"firstName\":true}; Expected type AccountFilter_exists to be an object at value.firstName.",
      "extensions": {
        "category": "graphql"
      },
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 1,
          "column": 19
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Does anyone know where I am going wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to provide the exists filters in this format:

```
{
  "exists": [{"firstName": true}]
}
```

https://api-platform.com/docs/v2.7/core/graphql/#syntax-for-filters-with-a-list-of-key--value-arguments

Hope this helps.